# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar variables ingresadas por teclado en el comando sar de linux en un programa en C?

Tags: c, linux, scanf

Quiero que los datos ingresados por teclado sean utilizados en el comando sar. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
    int tiempo;
    int numero;

    printf("Escriba el numero que desea : ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);
    printf("Escriba el tiempo que desea: ");
    scanf("%d",&tiempo);

    system("sar 1 5 > hi.txt");

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Échale un vistazo a la función `sprintf`, te puede servir para reemplazar ese 1 y ese 5 que tienes hardcodeados por los valores de las variables `numero` y `tiempo`.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función sprintf para imprimir en un string.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (void){
        int tiempo;
        int numero;
        printf("Escriba el numero que desea : ");
        scanf("%d",&numero);
        printf("Escriba el tiempo que desea: ");
        scanf("%d",&tiempo);
        char commando[30];
        sprintf(commando, "sar %i %i > hi.txt", numero, tiempo);
        system(commando);
        return(0);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me fue de gran ayuda!